# Error: wb_motor_set_velocity() called with negative 'velocity' argument in position control mode (2.38406e-05)

Tags: webots

I just tried to reset simulation, but pycharm reported this error to me. I did not set anything about the position. I just used a negative speed value on the motor, but there was no problem before reset. Please tell me. what do I do?

```
from controller import Supervisor

robot = Supervisor()


keyboard = robot.getKeyboard()
timestep = int(robot.getBasicTimeStep())
keyboard.enable(timestep)

while robot.step(timestep) != -1:
    key = keyboard.getKey()
    if key == ord('1'):
        # keyboard.disable()
        robot.simulationReset()
        print("Reset performed.")
        keyboard.enable(timestep)
    elif key == ord('2'):
        motor_1 = robot.getDevice("motor1")
        motor_1.setPosition(float("inf"))
        motor_1.setVelocity(-1.0)
    elif key == ord('3'):
        break
```

This code will not cause problems, but when using my reinforcement learning code, an error will be reported

Comment: To add, I use simulationresetphysics() and it has no effect